# Pass parameter to different actions in the same contrôler asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

i need your help please ,
I am using asp.net core and i need to pass the same parameter to 2 different actions that return a string and call those 2 actions to get there result in a third action that result a view. Any help please?

Comment: Any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Comment: yes actually it does, thank you so much for your help :) , i have created another method to retrieve data from both actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could directly create a new action which could receive the same parameter.

For example:

You have below three action:

```
    public string ActionA(string parameterA, string parameterB)
    {
        return parameterA + parameterB;
    }

    public string ActionB(string parameterA, string parameterB)
    {
        return parameterA + parameterB + "This ActionB";
    }


    public IActionResult ActionC()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Then you could create an actionD which could receive the parameter and call ActionA and ActionB.

```
    public IActionResult ActionD(string parameterA, string parameterB)
    {
        string resultA = ActionA(parameterA, parameterB);
        string resultB = ActionB(parameterA, parameterB);

        return View(resultA + resultB);
    }
```